Filter object members by type
I'm trying to filter an object by member type, and here's my implementation so far:
type FilterByType<T, M, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P] extends M ?
      M extends T[P] ?
        T[P]
      : never
    : never;
  };

type Example = FilterByType<{a: number; b: string}, number>;

let t: Example = {
  a: 1,
  b: '2', // this correctly errors, because 'b' is of type `never`
};

Now here is the problem:
let k: (keyof Example)[] = ['a', 'b']; // this doesn't error

What I want to happen: this should error because b is not a number. It currently doesn't because TypeScript doesn't filter the member b out of the object signature.
TypeScript is generating this signature:
type Example = {
  a: number;
  b: never;
}

I've also tried this alternative solution, but it still doesn't work:
type FilterByType<T, M, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  [P in Extract<
    K,
    T[K] extends M ?
      M extends T[K] ?
        K
      : never
    : never
  >]: T[P];
};

So, how do I get it to produce this signature while omitting the undesired keys:
type Example = {
  a: number;
}


This works:
type FilterByType<T, M, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  [P in K as T[P] extends M
    ? M extends T[P]
      ? T[P] extends never
        ? never
        : P
      : never
    : never]: T[P];
};

Which basically is this:
type FilterNeverKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K];
};

Or:
type Check<T, M, P extends keyof T> = T[P] extends M
  ? M extends T[P]
    ? T[P] extends never
      ? never
      : P
    : never
  : never;

type FilterByType<T, M, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  [P in K as Check<T, M, P>]: T[P];
};


You can rather extract keys and pick them from the type:
Playground
type FilterByType<T, M> = Pick<T, {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends M ? P: never
}[keyof T]>

type Example = FilterByType<{a: number; b: string}, number>;

let t: Example = {
  a: 1,
  b: '2', // 'b' does not exist in type 'Example'
};

let k: (keyof Example)[] = ['a', 'b']; // Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"a"'

